# how to bind checkbox value from datatable in gridview

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding, gridview, checkbox

I need to figure out how to bind a CheckBox value in a GridView, I have written CheckBox.Checked= DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsSubscribed") in GridView, but the CheckBox is always checked, even when `IsSubscribed` is false.

I have bound the grid in `Page_Load`, before the page has posted back. Here is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select"> 
     <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:CheckBox 
            ID="chkIsSubscribed" runat="server" HeaderText="IsSubscribed" 
            Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsSubscribed") %>'/>  
     </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks.

Comment: please post ur code and u bind the grid in !ispostback so it will not call everytime on page load

Comment: I have binded grid in !ispostback,My code is:     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsSubscribed" runat="server" HeaderText="IsSubscribed" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsSubscribed") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: what value for is IsSubscribed returning is it returns the 0 or 1 or something else

Comment: Just seeing "Checked" resolved for me.  I copied and pasted from a texbox. :)

Answer (score 18):

Put this code as your Item Template element:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsSubscribed" runat="server" HeaderText="IsSubscribed" 
        Checked='<%#bool.Parse(Eval("IsSubscribed").ToString())%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select"> 
     <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:CheckBox 
          ID="chkIsSubscribed" runat="server" HeaderText="IsSubscribed" 
          Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsSubscribed")) %>'/>  
     </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

please use this......

Comment: This solution took care of the Format Exception: `String was not recognized as a valid Boolean`

Answer (score 4):

Eval() give an object type.
So you have to use Eval(..).ToString() if you want to compare it...
Like:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actif">
            <ItemTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsACTIF" runat="server" Enabled="false" Checked='<%# (Eval("ACTIF").ToString() == "1" ? true : false) %>' /></ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="chkACTIF" runat="server" Checked='<%# (Eval("ACTIF").ToString() == "1" ? true : false) %>' Enabled="true" /></EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="chkNewACTIF" runat="server" Checked="true" /></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```