# Checkbox refused to bind data

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

When the data is loaded into the gridview, the boolean values should show in the checkboxes. Checkbox should be in editable format.

I am getting number of errors: Invalid cast, String is not in valid format etc.

I searched in Google and here as well. There are number of devs who faced same or similar issues and have managed to get it solved.

`Mon_S1` is a boolean (true, false). Changed to string to test out following code snippets.

- [1 : changed the values in db to be string and gives : System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18482132) and - [3 : same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7411058/2061309)

`checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("Mon_S1").ToString()) %>'`

- [2 : with bool values : System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/361831/System-InvalidCastException-Specified-cast-is-not)

`checked='<%# Eval("Mon_S1") %>'`

- [4 : this shows an empty editable checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8799986/2061309)

`checked='<%# Eval("Mon_S1").ToString().Equals("1") %>'`
`checked='<%# Bind("Mon_S1").ToString().Equals("1") %>'`

But no matter what combination of the answers I tried, it's not displaying the data as per the db which infact has boolean values.

Stacktrace for the following cast error:

```
Line 143:        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MS1">
Line 144:            <ItemTemplate>
Line 145:                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbMS1" runat="server" checked='<%# Eval("Mon_S1") %>'/>
Line 146:            </ItemTemplate>
Line 147:        </asp:TemplateField>
```

---

**Stack Trace:**

```
[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   ASP.testschedule_aspx.__DataBinding__control38(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Test - 0509 working\TestSchedule.aspx:145
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +85
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +187
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +94
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +187
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +94
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +167
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3724
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +67
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +123
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   TestSchedule.TestSchedule.BindGridViewDataSchedule() in C:\Test - 0509 working\TestSchedule.aspx:39
   TestSchedule.TestSchedule.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Test - 0509 working\TestSchedule.aspx.cs:22
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of mentioning all  errors you should mention which approach reaised what exception.

Comment: I am editing @TimSchmelter

Comment: And show your exception message and stack trace as a text.

Comment: What is the type of the property Mon_S1?

Comment: If Mon_S1 is not of a Boolean type you will get cast error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of  keep struggling with aspx and all the `Eval` approaches you could already be finished by using codebehind, use the `GridView`'s `RowDataBound`-event:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) e.Row.FindControl("cbMs1");
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        chk.Checked = row.Field<bool>("Mon_S1");
    }
}
```

**Update**: Since it seems to be nullable according to your comment, use this:

```
bool? nullOrTrue = row.Field<bool?>("Mon_S1");
chk.Checked = nullOrTrue.HasValue && nullOrTrue.Value;
```

If it's actually not a `bool` but a `string` change `row.Field<bool>` to `row.Field<string>`. The benefit of codebehind is that you have compile time safety and debugging capability.

So even if this gives you also an exception you can fix it easily. You just need to set a breakpoint at the first line and expect the values in the debugger's quick watch window. There you can find out what types are actually involved. Maybe `e.Row.DataItem` is not a `DataRowView`, then just look at it in debugger and use the correct type.

I also prefer to not use frontend for my business logic [for other reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_logic).

Comment: I am trying this out now. The reason I didn't want to use code behind because there are a large number of checkboxes in this gridview. It's a schedule for employees. So they can check/uncheck it. Depending on the number of employees for a particular group, there can be 100+ checkboxes loaded into the gridview at a time. I personally dislike to use gridview, but I am not familiar using ajax or other html stuff to do the job.

Comment: I am receiving the same cast error at `chk.Checked = row.Field<bool>("Mon_S1");` When changed to string, ofcourse the code has an error since the Mon_S1 data is bool.

Comment: @aspiring: then use `row.Field<string>("Mon_S1")=="1"` or `row["Mon_S1"].ToString()=="1"` or `row.Field<string>("Mon_S1")=="true"`. Inspect the value in the debugger, what does it show? Maybe you should change the column the database to use `bit` instead of `string`.

Comment: 100 checkboxes in a single row of a gridview? Poor user.

Comment: Not a single row. Entire gridview. Single row still has at worst 21 checkboxes... this looks like pretty bad design.

Comment: I am trying to handle null since there's a new error now. `System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Boolean'. Please use a nullable type.`

Comment: If it's a nullable bool use `bool? nullOrTrue = row.Field<bool?>("Mon_S1")`. Edited my answer.

Comment: Linq at its bes!. The test data was not creating values for all rows where checkboxes needed a value. So it breaks in null exception. I also took @Yu Yenkan's comment about explicitly defining data type of the data column in the datatable. I am going to test it out without datatype and see if your code solely solves everything as well. +1 and for now I am accepting this as answer - becasue it let me learn quite alot. Since you are .Net legend, please enlighten me with this: Is there a better way to design a web page rather than using a gridview like ASP controls?

Comment: @aspiring: depends on what you are trying to achieve. I also used `GridView` a lot, so there's nothing bad in using it.

Comment: the gridview must have **batch update** functionality with one final button event. So it shouldn't use the built in edit, update events. That's why I find it very difficult to use. User wants to click all the checkboxes and then update/insert to the db. Any suggestion of a workaround or other avenues that I could take to do it?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using .toString() and .Equals("1") at asp.net side;

```
Checked='<%# Eval("Mon_S1").ToString().Equals("1") %>'
```

why don you pass a boolean value?

```
Checked='<%# Eval("Checked") %>'
```

by adding a column with bool in Datatable or datasource

```
DataTable["Checked"] = true
```

if you need to bind to grid view.

Comment: The Stacktrace is on this error: `Checked='<%# Eval("Mon_S1") %>` where `Mon_S1` is a boolean value...

Comment: did you sure your Mon_S1 is boolean type?, make the datacolumn with typeof(Boolean) better

Comment: when you declare `DataTable` you can define `DataColumn` variable type by `dt.columns.add(new DataColumn("Checked",typeof(Boolean));`

Comment: The last comment of yours make lots of sense. So I marked you up. I am trying to narrow down to exact error.